# how to display end of line with join mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

1. table user
2. table activity a
3. table activity b

I want to retrieve all the data in the user table and all the last data in the table of activities a and b, like this :
[image: overview result]

how do i do sql writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, I would recommend using `row_number()` and `left join`:

```
select u.*, a.*, b.*
from user u left join
     (select a.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by id_user order by date_a desc) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a
     on a.id_user = u.id_user and a.seqnum = 1 left join
     (select b.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by id_user order by date_b desc) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on b.id_user = u.id_user and b.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: is this ok for the server? because after I tried it it took time to collect data .. I have 1 million data

Comment: @Arifhidayah . . . This is a very reasonable solution.  An index on `id_user`/`date` would help performance.